What is the correct way to post a portable solution to a platform-specific question?
In short: I posted solutions as a new Q&A question and as an answer and they were all deleted.
I wanted to know how to print my compiler version in a way that works for multiple compilers.
This question was specific to GCC (question text and tag were about gcc):
Output Compiler Version in a C++ Program, but it (along with some other answers) helped me figure out how to do more portably.
To share my new knowledge, I posted a similar question that's specifically about portability:
How can I print the version of the C++ compiler used that works for many compilers?.
I thought it'd also be useful to post a similar answer on the original question.
My answer on the original question was deleted as an identical answer. Trying to "Undelete" gives an error: "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted." My question was marked as duplicate. I tried editing my question to clarify that it's for more portable solutions, but my reopen request was refused.
At first, I thought being a dupe was fine since at least it's still discoverable, but now my question is deleted too. The end result is that my answer was deleted from everywhere and completely hidden from normal users.
What can I do to revive my answer and what should I do in the future to avoid deletion?

They were deleted as a duplicate or closed? Duplicate questions are not typically deleted. You can flag the answer to the duplicate question with a custom moderator flag. Keep in mind if you submitted an answer to your own question and the original question then it was a duplicate answer. Probably should have tried to get the question reopened or delete the answer before submitting the same answer to multiple questions. Furthermore, one moderator might have handled the duplicate answer, because it was flagged without know the closed question would eventually be deleted

"but it (along with some other answers) helped me figure out how to do more portably. To share my new knowledge, I posted a similar question that's specifically about portability: How can I print the version of the C++ compiler used that works for many compilers?." The problem here is that you aren't actually demonstrating a portable technique. You're showing how to use compiler switches to detect the compiler and then do the appropriate compiler-specific thing for each. So the corresponding question needs more focus.

note: there are portable answers in the referenced dup target

Now that your question is deleted (can't comment on if that is correct or not, I'm not a SME) you can flag your answer that was deleted by a moderator and denote in the flag that the original question is deleted, and thus the answer isn't a duplicate any more. Of course, if your question gets undeleted, you'll need to delete the answer on it instead.

@SecurityHound: The question was flagged as a duplicate and then around a month later it was deleted. I cannot use the Undelete option, but didn't try Flag. That let me mark it "In need of moderator intervention" and explain about deletion. We'll see what happens. Thanks for the pointer!

There's no actual portable solution because it's not part of the C++ spec. The best we have is using boost (the sole solution in the original question for multiple compilers) or having some minimal code snippet that handles several compilers. I was hoping to make a question that invited people to improve on my solution to the latter.
